# How to include <emscripten/emscripten.h>

Tags: c++, cmake, webassembly

What do I need to add to my CMakeLists.txt file such that below examples from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAssembly/C_to_wasm) can still build?

I can generate the WASM with out any problems but have no idea what to add to my CMakeLists.txt to stop getting the error, when trying to just run the c code

> fatal error: 'emscripten/emscripten.h' file not found
> #include <emscripten/emscripten.h>

I tried finding examples but sadly I found none.

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <emscripten/emscripten.h>
    
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    printf("Hello World\n");
}
    
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
    
EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE void myFunction(int argc, char ** argv) {
    printf("MyFunction Called\n");
}
    
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

My CMakeLists.txt is barebones at the moment and contains the following:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(WASM)
    
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
    
add_executable(WASM main.cpp)
```

Comment: I think you need to add `emscripten/emscripten.h` to `add_executable` list before `main.cpp`

Comment: So did you _install_ `emscripten`?

Comment: @KamilCuk It cam with python 3.6 which I already had installed.

Comment: So where is `empcripten.h` file installed?

Comment: @KamilCuk I found it using find command at usr/local/Cellar/emscripten/2.0.10/libexec/system/include/emscripten/emscripten.h

Comment: You pass proper `CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE` parameter to `cmake` when configure the project, don't you? With that parameter the compiler should be set to `emcc`/`em++`, so it should be aware where to find `emscripten/emscripten.h`. Assuming you build project with `make`, you may call it as `make VERBOSE=1` and it will print exact command line used for compiling. Please, show that command line (add it to the question post).

Answer (score 2):

Be sure to use the emsdk provided cmake wrapper script called `emcmake` upon configuration. The script takes care of setting up the compilation enviroment for emsdk, i.e.:

```
   $ mkdir build
   $ cd build
   $ /path/to/emcmake cmake ..
   $ make
```

Also see the following [Github issue](https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/issues/10412).